# Outgoing exchange email receive at client spam folder

Tags: email-server, exchange-2013

Firstly, I am newbie for Exchange server.
I just had setup 1 test Exchange server 2013 from my company lab. I have finished configured sending out email via internet. However, at my external client email box (gmail) they received my emails at spam folder not inbox folder.
Do i need to do anything else if my email will receive at inbox folder?
Thank you so much and i really appreciate your help.

Comment: We need more information here to help you. We need the header from the email received in the gmail mailbox. This header will include mostly some infos why this email was recognized as SPAM. For example it could be that you are using a blacklisted IP.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your "Do i need to do anything" question:

On receiver side, open the email and check the header (in the source). The header contains mostly some X-Headers flags.

For example (from [SpamAssasin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/)):

> ```
> X-Spam-Flag: NO
> X-Spam-Score: -1.779
> X-Spam-Level:
> X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.779 tagged_above=-999 required=5 tests=[BAYES_00=-2.599, MSOE_MID_WRONG_CASE=0.82]
> ```

This helps you to understand why the email was catched as SPAM. Based on that finding you can try to solve the issue.

Additional you can check if your Server is BlackListed (for example [here](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)).